# Can an MVC Controller class have more than one IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Would it be possible for me to do two LINQ queries and then return the results of each as IEnumerable or would  the queries need to be combined and how would you accomplish  that?

Comment: Are the IEnumerable's related? You could use .Join or .Concat if you just want to return both arrays together.

Comment: If you are meaning pass two ienumerables to thw view, a viewmodel might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @JasonEvans, evidently nothing - it's like nobody *tries* anything anymore.  Remember when there was no internet?!  *Grumbles about uphill both ways*...

Comment: @Moo-Juice Cut the guy some slack. He asked a reasonable question. Unfair of you to presume he had enough knowledge to propose a suggestion for something he clearly needs more information on. We all started somewhere...

Comment: @DPeden, indeed!  But this is *very basic stuff*.  I admit I was perhaps a little curt, but the question title doesn't make any sense and the author clearly has no idea how things *work*.  This site (in my humble opinion) is not a "learning to program" site - there are *oodles* of resources on the internet to solve these basic questions.  Books, tutorials, courses, you name it.  Do you want this site to be a gathering ground for every conceivable "I didn't bother searching or learning" question?  Sorry if this comes across rude (not to you), but it *does* irk me.  Happy New Year :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice Agreed. The better approach, IMO, would be to point him to one of those sites so that our community as a whole improves and you get one more person capable of *answering* these types of questions.

Comment: I do understand that this is a basic question, as I am new to asp.net mvc and an working on my first program. Are sites like Stack Overflow so people with experience can feel superior to beginners?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your controller can return more than one IEnumerable from an action.

This would be done as follows:

**ViewModel**

```
    public class FooModel
    {
        public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public List<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubCategory
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller action**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new FooModel();
        var categories = new List<Category>();
        var subCategories = new List<SubCategory>();

        categories.Add(new Category { Id = 1, Description = "Cat 1" });
        categories.Add(new Category { Id = 2, Description = "Cat 2" });
        subCategories.Add(new SubCategory { Id = 1, Description = "Sub-Cat 1", CategoryId = 1 });
        subCategories.Add(new SubCategory { Id = 2, Description = "Sub-Cat 2", CategoryId = 2 });

        model.Categories = categories;
        model.SubCategories = subCategories.Where(s => s.Id == 1).ToList();


        return View(model);
    }
```

In the above `FooModel` (view model) contains two lists that are returned from the Controller `Index` action.